# How to change textLabel so it doesnt overlap the detailtextlabel on table view

Tags: iphone, tableview, textlabel

IMAGE: http://postimage.org/image/35y3ji58k

the problem can be seen, in which most display okay but the names continue to overlap the detail title.

i would like the textlabel to have the "..." like the detail label and the detail label to always show.

so basicilly switch the formatting around.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should subclass the `UITableViewCell` and create your own `CustomUITableViewCell` and then set a good frame size for the `self.textLabel`.

That should resolve the issue.